# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in React hooks fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

Hello everyone and thanks for reading this.
I am trying to hit an API but it returns a big data ( array of 6000 elements ), so i have to wait for few seconds to page get rendered. Also i am getting range error for maximum callbacks.
Am I missing something or the API has a problem? any possible fix? here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function SomeName() {
  const [archive, setArchive] = useState([]);
  const getArchive = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://anaddress");
    const body = JSON.parse(await response.text());
    setArchive(body.splice(4))
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getArchive();
  }, []);

return ( <div> Some JSX to render archive </div>)
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this mainly happens because of infinite recursion ,your use effect hook make call to getArchive recursively, you need to make sure that its only called once when your archive array is empty. you can archive this by checking archive array length before making call to fetch ,as below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function SomeName() {
const [archive, setArchive] = useState([]);
const getArchive = async () => {
  
const response = await fetch("https://anaddress");
const body = JSON.parse(await response.text());
setArchive(body.splice(4));
};

useEffect(() => {
   if(archive.length ==0){
        getArchive();
      }
     
}, []);

 return ( <div> Some JSX to render archive </div>)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by replacing the:

```
setArchive(body.splice(4));
```

with:

```
body.splice(4);
setArchive(body);
```

Also I noticed that I don't need to put "[]" for my useEffect.